# UIView animation was canceled by a system for an unclear reason

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uicollectionview, performbatchupdates

I have an insert animation for UICollectionCell (like slide-in), I called the insert animation in this method `-collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:`.
Everything just works fine when I called this `[self.collectionView reloadData];` to reload data. In this way, the animation will be shown currently.

```
------------
A
------------
<= inserted C (slide-in Animation)
------------
B
------------
```

But when I tried to add another animation to this inserted cell (like slide-down), things went wrong. 
Instead of using `-reloadData`, I used `[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:completion:]` and a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout with `initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath` method to implement the slide down animation.

```
------------
A
------------
------------ <= inserted C (Second, slide-in animation)
B （First, slide-down animation）
------------
```

In the cell, the log of animation's delegate method `animationDidStop:finished:` shows that the `finished = NO`

```
UICollectionCell：
- (void)setAnimationInLayer:(CALayer *)layer
{
    CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
    anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(layer.bounds.size.width * 0.33f)];
    anim.toValue  = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    CABasicAnimation *opacityAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    opacityAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    opacityAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1];
    CAAnimationGroup *animGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    animGroup.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:anim,opacityAnim, nil];
    animGroup.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    animGroup.duration = 5.5f;
    animGroup.delegate = self;
    [layer addAnimation:animGroup forKey:nil];
}
- (void)animationDidStart:(CAAnimation *)animation
{
    NSLog(@"-------> %s",__func__);
    NSLog(@"%f",[self.articlesCollection.layer presentationLayer].frame.origin.x);
}
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)animation finished:(BOOL)finished
{
    NSLog(@"-------> %s finished: %d",__func__,finished);
    NSLog(@"%f",[self.articlesCollection.layer presentationLayer].frame.origin.x);
}
```

To sum up, when I use `-performBatchUpdates:completion` instead of `-reloadData`, every animation of UICollectionView disappeared.
So the question is what situation may cause an animation disappear? 
I mean looks like it has been removed from the layer it is attached to. But I didn't do that. Any idea?

Comment: Any reason you're not using the new `UIViewPropertyAnimator` class?

Comment: Yea, still based on iOS 9.

Comment: Well, I guess it's somehow related to viewController transition